# Java function not working when called twice

Tags: java

```
public static int getMinor(int[][] mat, int r, int c) {
  int minor = 0;
  int[] min = new int[4];
  int x = 0;
  while (x <= 3) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (i != r && j != c && mat[i][j] != 100) {
          min[x] = mat[i][j];
          x += 1;
          mat[i][j] = 100;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  minor = min[0] * min[3] - min[1] * min[2];
  return minor;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[][] mat = getMatrix();
  System.out.println(getMinor(mat, 0, 0));
  System.out.println(getMinor(mat, 1, 1));
}
```

for some reason when I call `getMinor` function again the code stops working.
It prints the minor the first time but does not work when I call it again in the next line.
`getMatrix` function just gets the matrix.

Comment: You are altering `mat` in `getMinor`. Is that intentional? This means the second call to `getMinor` will have the altered `mat` from the first call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains the potential for an infinite loop. It is possible for `(x <= 3)` to never become `false`, and so for your `while` loop to run forever.  You haven't given your input matrix, but I assume that what is happening is that the first call to `getMinor` returns and so `println` prints the returned result, but then the execution goes into `getMinor` the second time and gets stuck...never comes out, and so the second `println` never occurs and the program never exits.

Yes, that's what's going on. I just made up an arbitrary matrix, and my run prints a `0` and then locks up in the second call to `getMinor`, going around and around in the `while` loop forever with `if (i != r && j != c && mat[i][j] != 100)` never being `true`, and so `x` never changing.  This occurs because you're operating on the same matrix the second time, and the locations already set to `100` are sufficient to cause the `while` loop to never exit.

If you start with a fresh matrix the second time, this doesn't so easily occur. This code, at least with my sample matrix, completes:

```
int[][] mat = getMatrix();
System.out.println(getMinor(mat, 0, 0));
mat = getMatrix();
System.out.println(getMinor(mat, 1, 1));
```

Another potential problem with your code (I say potential because maybe you will never use the wrong parameters so that this happens) is if you pass in `r` and `c` values that are larger than the w/h bounds of the matrix, then the program crashes with an `index out of bounds error` because the `if` clause succeeds more than 4 times in a run through the matrix, and so you haven't allocated enough slots in the `min` array, and `min[x] = mat[i][j];` goes bang!.

Answer (score 0):

1. You've changed the value of "mat" in "getMinor", so 2ed call dose not have same input as the 1st one . (You may read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) to figure out java's "pass by reference" VS  "pass by value")
2. It's not a good practice to modify input within a function named as "getXXX"